# Build dependency in CMake

Tags: cmake

I want to build and use Botan linked statically in my application, which means first

```
python configure.py --disable shared
```

followed by

```
make
```

And then I'd like to create a dependency target for libbotan.a as "libbotan" that I can use in the rest of my CMake files. Since Botan not using CMake I'm not sure how to include the dependency in my project.

My current attempt looks like this:

in deps/Botan.1.11.7/CmakeLists.txt

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT botan-configure COMMAND ./configure.py --disable-shared)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT botan-build COMMAND make DEPENDS botan-configure)
add_custom_target(botan DEPENDS botan-configure botan-build)
```

but when I added botan as a dependency in core/CMakeLists.txt like this

```
add_executable(console console.cpp)
target_link_libraries(console messages core botan ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

I get

```
CMake Error at simpleclient/CMakeLists.txt:5 (target_link_libraries):
 Target "botan" of type UTILITY may not be linked into another target.  One
 may link only to STATIC or SHARED libraries, or to executables with the
 ENABLE_EXPORTS property set.
```

I tried using ExternalProject_Add like this

```
ExternalProject_Add(botan
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/randombit/botan.git
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND python configure.py --disable-shared
    BUILD_COMMAND make
    INSTALL_COMMAND make install
)
```

But that gives me the same error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) module:

> The 'ExternalProject_Add' function creates a custom target to drive
> download, update/patch, configure, build, install and test steps of an
> external project

Note that this will only create a utility target. That is, you may run the target to build the library and you may add dependencies from your project's targets to the utility target. You can *not* however link to the target directly.

You still need to obtain the paths to the library and include directories of the external project manually. Since the project in question does not seem to use CMake by itself, that means writing your own calls to [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html), [`find_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_path.html), etc. and use the results from those calls to properly integrate the dependency.

Since the external project is built as part of your normal CMake run it should be quite easy to obtain the correct values by searching in the install path given to `ExternalProject_Add`.

However, there is an additional complication: The build managed by `ExternalProject` will execute as part of the *build* of your enclosing project, but for the `find_*` calls to succeed, it needs to be able to find the library files already during the CMake configure run (so *before* you start building). You have two options to resolve this:

- Hardcode the library paths for the external project into your build. This really only works for the most simple cases and is not recommended in general. In particular for dependencies that provide [CMake config files](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#config-file-packages) as part of their install step, you will lose a lot of information from the original build that you will have to painfully replicate in the enclosing project's build configuration.
- Run `ExternalProject` not as part of your build, but move it to its own CMake project that you configure *and build* during the initial CMake configuration of your enclosing project. That way, when CMake reaches the `find_package` call, the dependency has already been fully built and installed within your CMake binary directory. The disadvantage here is that the external project is only built once when running CMake and will not automatically rebuild when you touch one of the external project's source files. In most cases you won't touch the sources of external dependencies anyway, so this is not a problem, but be aware of this limitation.

Comment: @dutt My bad, expanded the answer.

Comment: "it should be quite easy to obtain the correct values by searching in the install path given to ExternalProject_Add." If it is so easy, why not just explain this step? :) It's not obvious to me...

Comment: @HannesLandeholm I did not explain it, as it is highly dependent on the project you want to add. What I meant is that you have to manually inspect the contents of the install folder after installation for this. Basically, look where it copies its libraries and headers within the install directory. Since the install tree is usually quite lean, this should be straightforward, but your mileage may vary of course depending on the external library.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Unfortunately, I had to downvote this accepted answer. The main issue is that `ExternalProject_Add` runs at build time, while `find_library`, `find_package`, `pkg_check_modules` etc runs at configure time. So the suggested solution doesn't work, and this issue is not addressed by the answer, and is the main challenge to solve when using `ExternalProject_Add` (and in general when building dependencies from cmake).

Comment: To be clear, this solution doesn't work because find_library would not be able to locate a library that is not built/installed yet.

Comment: It seems like the few people using the (broken IMHO) `ExternalProject_Add` feature then use hardcoded paths instead of `find_package` or `find_library`: https://github.com/vgteam/libvgio/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @aberaud You are completely right and I am a little embarrassed I did not notice this oversight before. I added a new section to the answer to elaborate on the issues you mentioned. I agree that `ExternalProject_Add` is kind of broken because of this, but keep in mind also that this is a question dating back to CMake 2.8 times and the selection of tools for managing external dependencies (both within CMake and in the C++ ecosystem as a whole) was significantly more limited back then compared to today. Thanks for taking the time to point out the issues!