# How to install library from add_subdirectory in current directory

Tags: cmake, luajit

I'm using [LuaDist's LuaJIT](https://github.com/LuaDist/luajit) and I'm trying to add it to my CMake project via add_subdirectory. It seems to build the solution, but it doesn't actually make the libs. How do I tell the sub_directory to also make and install? Do I need to edit that project's CMake, or can I do it from my CMake project (preferred)?

Additionally, when I build and install LuaJIT seperately it installs to C:\Program Files (x86). I don't want that when I build it from my project. I want it to install to my projects \lib\LuaJIT directory (or basically build in place).

```
# lua
message( STATUS "Building Lua")
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/luajit/src)
add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/luajit)
```

Comment: Subprojects included with `add_subdirectory()`  are *installed* when main project is *installed*. If you want the subproject to be already installed while you build main project, include it via [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html) instead. Using this module you may also adjust build and install directories for subproject.

Comment: When I use ExternalProject_Add(luajit SOURCE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/luajit) and
target_link_libraries(EtherEngine gtest gtest_main luajit ) I get "1>   Target "luajit" of type UTILITY may not be linked into another target.  One
1>   may link only to STATIC or SHARED libraries, or to executables with the
1>   ENABLE_EXPORTS property set."

What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Target `luajit` is created by `ExternalProject_Add` function *itself*, this is **not** a **library target**. See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630360/build-dependency-in-cmake) for more explanations. You need to determine where library file is installed, and **use** the **file for linking** (or wrap it into *IMPORTED* library). This is how `add_subdirectory` approach differs from `ExternalProject` one: with first approach, you have access to every target of the project, with the last approach the project is installed as a "black box".